# Android - Stop AsyncTask when back button is pressed and return to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, back-button

I've an AsyncTask and I want it to stip execution when back button is pressed. I also want the app to return to the previous displayed Activity. It seems I've managed in stop the Task but the app doesn't return to the previous activity. Any ideas? This is an extract from my code

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements OnDismissListener{
    private boolean exception= false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(
                IscrizioniActivity.this,
                "Please wait...",
                "Loading the data",
                true,
                true,
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        MyTask.this.cancel(true);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //do something
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
        pd.dismiss();
        //do something

    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        this.cancel(true);
    }

}
```

Regards.

Comment: this answer may help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993023/stop-a-thread-downloading-images-when-activity-finishes/7993176#7993176

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pd.setCancelable(true);
    pd.setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
    bCancelled=false;

 pd is your progressdialog box
```

and now use  cancelListner

```
    OnCancelListener cancelListener=new OnCancelListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0){
        bCancelled=true;
        finish();
    }
};
```

Comment: It partly did the trick. I've canceled "implements OnDismissListner" and OnDismiss method. And added finis() in onCancel.

Comment: @pradeep it is used to boolean check whether it is cancelled or not

Answer (score 2):

In your activity, override Back Button, stop the AsyncTask in it, and call finish for current activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         MyTask.cancel();
      IscrizioniActivity.this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with MyTask.stop? No such method.

Comment: Now the problem is on YourCurrentActivity.finish(). Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method finish() from the type Activity

Comment: I know that. I had to put this before finis(). Now I'll check if it works.

Comment: Tried it. It stops the ecexution (like before) but doesn't return to previous activity. I have to push the back button again.

Comment: I call the Activity through an Intent

Comment: put there startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity() and override onActivityResult() in that activity. then these works.

Comment: I've solved my problem. I've explained my code in the comment to Raghav Chopra's answer. As soon as I'll be able to answer my own question I'll copy the full code. For posterity :) Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `finish()` call in the `onDismiss()` method:

```
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    this.cancel(true);
    IscrizioniActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
progress_dialog.setCancelable(true);
progress_dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        YourActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
```